# class Database extends OneDatabase

Tags: php

I'm trying to conform to the Zend Coding Standard as well.

```
EDIT 2:

<?php

/**
 *    Input   :   Query request
 *    Output  :   A row or a list of rows
 *    Notes   :
 *
 *    Provides escaping and binding via PDO library
 *    Consolidates PDO to use a single calling mechanism
 *    Consolidates all queries to an associative array
 *    Mysqli available for those who wish to implement
 */

class Database extends OneDatabase
{
    private $dbResource;
    public function __construct()  
    {
        $this->dbResource = oneDatabase::_get();
    }
    public function getResource()
    {
        return $this->dbResource;
    }
    protected $_sqlArray = array(
        "signin_pass" => "SELECT pass FROM cr WHERE email=?",
        "signin_validate" => "SELECT email,pass FROM cr WHERE email=? AND pass=?",
        "signin_flname" => "SELECT flname FROM cr WHERE email=?",
        "signup_check" => "SELECT * FROM cr WHERE email=?",  
        "signup_insert" => "INSERT INTO cr VALUES (?,?,?)",
        "signup_site1" => "INSERT INTO bo VALUES ('Facebook','http://www.facebook.com','',?)",
        "signup_site2" => "INSERT INTO bo VALUES ('Twitter','http://www.twitter.com','',?)",
        "bookmark_delete" => "DELETE FROM bo WHERE name=? AND email=? LIMIT 1",
        "bookmark_insert" => "INSERT INTO bo VALUES (?, ?,'', ?)",
        "bookmark_model" => "SELECT * FROM bo WHERE email=? ORDER BY name ASC",
        "tweet_insert" => "INSERT INTO tw VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
        "tweet_model" => "SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7",
        "create_bookmark" => "CREATE TABLE bookmark(name VARCHAR(64), url VARCHAR(256), tag VARCHAR(256), id INT)",
        "create_credentials" => "CREATE TABLE credentials(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, flname VARCHAR(60), email VARCHAR(32), pass VARCHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY(id))",
        "create_tweet" => "CREATE TABLE tweet(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, flname VARCHAR(60), email VARCHAR(32), pass VARCHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY(id))"
    );
    public function _pdoQuery($fetchType, $queryType, $parameterArray) 
    {
        $query=$this->_sqlArray[$queryType];
        eval("\$query = \"$query\";");
        if($parameterArray==0)
        {
            $results = oneDatabase::$_database->query($query);
            return $results;
        }
        oneDatabase::$_database->quote($query);
        $pdoStatement = oneDatabase::$_database->prepare($query);
        $pdoStatement->execute($parameterArray);
        if($fetchType=='none')
        {
            $results=NULL;
        }
        else if($fetchType=='single')
        {
            $results = $pdoStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        else if($fetchType=='multiple')
        {
            $results = $pdoStatement->fetchAll();
        }
        return $results;
    }
    protected function _mysqliQuery($aquery) 
    {
        return oneDatabase::$_database->query($query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good thing about this code is your bracing style which is applied consistently and is visually appealing.  Now on to some improvements:

This code does not implement a Database.  (You have called the class Database, but it does not resemble something that looks like a database).  This class does not really have a good purpose.  If you are going to write a database class it should handle database type things.  Like transactions or methods for select, insert and delete statements etc.

Some other things:

- It is not easy to re-use the code.
- It contains hard coded values.
- It breaks up a logical separation of concerns for your program.
- Don't use eval - it is not good for your application security:
  `eval("\$query = \"$query\";");`
- oneDatabase::$_database can be replaced by $this->_database as you
  are extending that class.
- mysqli is mixed in with PDO.  Just use PDO.
- databaseCopy is not required
- method access should be specified (public, protected, private)

In summary, I think you should re-think your design.

Comment: I can use either one...but I chose oneDatabase::$_database becasue this lets me know that it is static.  In general I use $this for objects and class_name:: for classes (i.e. static members), even though it is not required.  This is preference, I don't see why it matters either way.

Comment: databaseCopy has been removed.

Comment: Is PDO standard in all PHP installations?  I left mysqli in case it is not in a standard installation and someone needs to revert.

Comment: Added in method access

Comment: How should I change the structure...as this seems to be the main issue...what is the reason this does not implement Database?  My database class take a query request...and returns with the needed data in the form of an array or an array of arrays.  This is my definition of a database class...what is yours?

Comment: My idea of a database class is similar to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5294/pdo-wrapper-class/  Once you have that Database class defined you would create an instance of it and use it (rather than extending from it).  In this way objects are created that do specific things.  Likewise when using your database class you should not extend from it, but rather use it as an object.  Then you will see how much your object is doing for you.  Right now it is an object that provides only one method.

Comment: PDO has been enabled by default since 5.1.0 (6 years ago).

Comment: I have conceptualized my Database class and OneDatabase class together as a cohesive unit.  And I do not extend from them.  But once again I do this as a matter of preference.

Comment: Even though PDO appears to be best practice...I assume people still use mysqli as it has been improved upon recently from just plain mysql, and b.c. it does no harm I leave it there.  Perhaps there are trade-offs I'm unaware of as well.

Comment: A query is a Query....if you know mysql..you don't need all of that..you just write the query...insert it in the array....and call it accordingly...much easier...1/5 the code...what is gained by blowing my code up 5X?  Why would I put my credentials in xml? Why would I decompose all the mySQL and spread it all over the place?

Comment: The reason to spread your SQL all over the place is that the logic will then be with the parts that are doing the work.  For example:  When you have an object that controls fruit, you would expect it to be able to add fruit, delete them, or modify them.  To have that SQL logic split out of the fruit class and put into this database class would make the fruit class unreadable and tightly coupled to this class.  So it would need this class in order to be reusable.

Comment: I have not fruit class or similar...if you want to use the database you need two classes OneDatabase and Database..that is it...if you create additional classes they in fact will be tied to to whatever class initiates the query...your talking about adding another layer of abstraction...a matter of preference...I could do it but I don't gain anything by the extra work and code...however if my list of queries will get absurdly long..then I will need to.